# India property and family law: intestate succession among siblings dead and/or alive

Tags: property, india

How is the property shared among siblings?

(Class 2 legal heirs are me and my deceased elder brother, who is survived by his wife and their 3 grownup kids, who are themselves married and have their own kids.)

The Inheritance falls under the Hindu Succession Act.

Do I get 50% of the inheritance or do I get a share of 20% like my brother's kids and his wife??

Comment: it's unclear who died: IS it the inheritance of *your brother* that is to to be solved?

Comment: We are class 2 heirs. My eldest brother died without a will. My widowed sister in law and her kids and me are who want to inherit. I don't know who gets to inherit and how it will be divided.

Comment: No class 1 heirs. Thank you trish

Comment: So, let me get this straight: Your Brother A died, his children and wife inherited. Your parents died and their estates are handled. now sibling B died and **his** estate is to be handled, and you as well as the descendants of Brother A are the only other possible heirs?

Comment: Brother B died. He has no wife. His wife died after he died.he has no wife or children who can inherit. His He was childless. She died after his death. He predeceased her. Yes the intestate inheritance of the brothe designated B is to be decided.  now sibling B died and his estate is to be handled, and you as well as the descendants of Brother A are the only other possible heirs. Yes I'm questioning whether the descendants of brother A are heirs and how they share it with me.